# save objects of inotify "events" in an array in c

Tags: c, events, inotify

I am working on sending the updates from `inotify` for the current directory in Linux through a client to server communication.

This is the code for the `inotify` section:

I showed the parts that are my concerns with `/*???    ???*/` since I don't know what to correctly work in that part.

```
#define EVENT_STRUCT_SIZE sizeof(struct inotify_event) 
#define BUFFER_SIZE (10 * (EVENT_STRUCT_SIZE + NAME_MAX + 1))
char buffer_[BUFFER_SIZE];

/*???
int arr_to_server[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
???*/

int inotify_fd = inotify_init();
    if(inotify_fd == -1)
        return 1; // can't create the inotify fd, return 1 to os and exit

    int watch_des = inotify_add_watch(inotify_fd, ".", IN_ALL_EVENTS);

    if(watch_des == -1)
        return 1; // can't create the watch descriptor, return 1 to os and exit

    // start to monitor
    while(1 == 1) {
        // read 
        int bytesRead = read(inotify_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE), bytesProcessed = 0;
        if(bytesRead < 0) // read error
            return 1;
        
        while(bytesProcessed < bytesRead) {
            struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*)(buffer_inot + bytesProcessed);

           /*??? 
           
            arr_to_server[0] = event->mask;
            arr_to_server[1] = event->name;


           ???*/
           bytesProcessed += EVENT_STRUCT_SIZE + event->len;
            //send(sock, arr_to_server, strlen(arr_to_server),0);
        }
        
    }
```

So essentially, `event` is a `struct` that has some `objects`, and among those objects, I want to save
`event->name event->mask`
in an array to be able to send the array from a client to the server using `arr_to_server`.

I have tried many things that I know based on my skills in c, but I am still paralyzed when it comes to very sophisticated details on data structures in c.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a simpler example first if you have not mastered basic data structures yet. In your case you don't actually need to create a new data structure (though you could). But you need to understand/define the data format that is being sent over the wire. Example:  call `send` once for `event->mask` and once for `event->name`. In this case the data would be a fixed size int followed by a fixed size char array. Note that you may be able to send a variable sized string but that could cause problems as the following int may start with a zero.

Comment: @kaylum So, essentially `serialization & deserialization` should be used to send the data. Additionally, I am not sure if two `send` calls consecutively would work especially if the server has multiple clients (of course for the multithread execution mutex is to be used)

I would be more comfortable to send an array rather than two send calls. But, of course I would go with the latter in case I did not find a solution.

Comment: Yes, need to serialise and deserialise. Of course multiple sends will work even with multiple clients. Each client would be on a different socket.

Comment: If you really must send an array then just declare an array of such structs. `struct entry { char name[MAX_NAME]; int mask; }; struct entry data[MAX_NUM_DATA];` Then copy: `strncpy(data[i].name, event->name, MAX_NAME); data[i].mask = event->mask;` and finally: `send(sock, data, sizeof(data), 0);`. Note that this sends the whole array even if it is not full. You can modify to optimise that.

Comment: @kaylum Would `send(socket, &event->mask, strlen(event->mask),0);` work? I still get warnings for it though.

Comment: No of course it won't work. And the warnings should tell you exactly why. `event->mask` is not a string so you can't use `strlen` on it. Notice my example? I didn't use `strlen` exactly for that reason.